I made Laravel CRUD api and I can't upload an image
for several days I have problem uploading an image with Laravel api. I was sending request via React's modified axios. Code is as follows.
axios-client.js
import axios from "axios";

const axiosClient = axios.create({
    baseURL : `${import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL}/api`
});

axiosClient.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('ACCESS_TOKEN');
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;

    if (config.data instanceof FormData) {
        console.log('Form Data accepted')
        config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';
    }

    return config;
});

axiosClient.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    return response;
}, (error) => {
    try {
        const { response } = error;
        if (response.status === 401) {
            localStorage.removeItem('ACCESS_TOKEN');
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
    throw error;
});

export default axiosClient;


React's component
BrandForm.jsx
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import axiosClient from '../../axios-client';

function BrandForm() {
  const {id} = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [loading,setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState(null);
  const [brand,setBrand] = useState({
    id: null,
    name: '',
    logo: null
  });
  const config = {headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}}

  if (id){
    useEffect(()=>{
        setLoading(true);
        axiosClient.get(`/car-make/${id}`)
            .then(({data})=>{
              console.log(data)
                setBrand(data);
                setLoading(false)
            })
            .catch((e)=>{
                console.log(e)
                setLoading(false);
            })
    },[]);
  }
  const onSubmit = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    setErrors(null);
    
    if (brand.id){
        axiosClient.put(`/car-make/${brand.id}`, brand, config)
        .then(({data})=>{
            //TODO show notification
            console.log('response update', data)
            navigate(path);
        })
        .catch( (err) => {
          console.log(err)
            const response = err.response;
            if(response && response.status ===422){
              setErrors(response.data.errors);
            }
          });
    } 
    else {
      
        axiosClient.post(`/car-make`, brand, config)
        .then(()=>{
            //TODO show notification
            console.log('response create', data)
            navigate(path);
        })
        .catch( (err) => {
            const response = err.response;
            if(response && response.status ===422){
              setErrors(response.data.errors);
            }
          });

    }

  }

  return (
    <div>
      {brand?.id ? <h1>Edit Brand: {brand.name}</h1> : <h1>New Brand</h1>}
      <div className="card animated fadeInDown">
        {loading && <div className="text-center">Loading...</div>}
        {errors && (
          <div className="alert">
            {Object.keys(errors).map((key) => (
              <p key={key}>{errors[key][0]}</p>
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
        {!loading && (
          <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <input
              value={brand?.name}
              onChange={(e) => setBrand({ ...brand, name: e.target.value })}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Name"
            />
            <input
              onChange={(e) => setBrand({ ...brand, logo: e.target.files[0] })}
              type="file"
              placeholder="Logo"
            />
            <button className="btn" style={{ marginTop: '20px' }}>Save</button>
          </form>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default BrandForm;

Laravel's
api.php
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function(){

    Route::put('/transfer/execute/{id}', [TransferController::class,'execute']);
    Route::put('/transfer/cancel/{id}', [TransferController::class,'cancel']);
    Route::apiResource('/transfer', TransferController::class);
    Route::apiResource('/vehicle', VehicleController::class);
  
    Route::apiResource('/car-make', CarMakeController::class);
    Route::apiResource('/car-model', CarModelController::class);

    Route::get('/companies/partner',[CompanyController::class,'indexPartner']);
    Route::get('/companies/fleet',[CompanyController::class,'indexFlota']);
    Route::apiResource('/companies', CompanyController::class);
    
    
    Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    });
    Route::post('/logout',  [AuthController::class,'logout']); 
    Route::apiResource('/users', UserController::class);

   
});


Route::post('/signup',  [AuthController::class,'signup']);
Route::post('/login',   [AuthController::class,'login']);

Model
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CarMake extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'logo'];
    protected $primarykey = "id";
    
  
    public function carModels()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CarModel::class,'make');
    }
}

Controller
.
.
.
public function update(UpdateCarMakeRequest $request, CarMake $carMake)
    {
        Log::info('Update method called');
        Log::info('Update Brand Request - Raw Request Data:', $request->all());
        
        $data = $request->validated();
    
        if ($request->hasFile('logo')) {
            $file = $request->file('logo');
            $fileName = time() . '_' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $filePath = $file->storeAs('logo', $fileName, 'public');
            $data['logo'] = $filePath;
        } else {
            unset($data['logo']);
        }
    
        Log::info('Update Brand Request - Validated Data:', $data);
    
        $carMake->update($data);
    
        return new CarMakeResource($carMake);
    }
.
.
.

Update Request
class UpdateCarMakeRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true; // Adjust as needed
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'logo' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ];
    }

    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        Log::error('Validation errors:', $validator->errors()->toArray());
        throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json([
            'errors' => $validator->errors()
        ], 422));
    }
}


Reource
class CarMakeResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function toArray(Request $request): array
    {
        return [
            'id'=> $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'logo'=> $this->logo,
        ];

    }
}

The Log file looks like this after trying to edit
[2024-07-18 05:29:50] local.ERROR: Validation errors: {"name":["The name field is required."]} 
[2024-07-18 05:44:36] local.ERROR: Validation errors: {"name":["The name field is required."]} 


Note: when I try updating CarMake without an image and without config parameter in axios
request it works fine
Thanks in advance for your effort!

It was my try to force Content-Type in request but didn't help. Main purpose of this interceptor is to send Bearer data with request.

Your request interceptor data handling is completely redundant. Axios already handles FormData payloads and does so correctly. Yours is missing the mime boundary token.
Remove this and let Axios and your browser set the appropriate content-type header

if (config.data instanceof FormData) {
  console.log('Form Data accepted')
  config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';
}


You also cannot embed files in a JSON document. Create a FormData instance for your request payload, populate the data and send that
const onSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setErrors(null);

  const fd = new FormData();
  Object.entries(brand).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (value !== null) fd.append(key, value);
  });

  try {
    if (brand.id) {
      await axiosClient.put(`/car-make/${encodeURIComponent(brand.id)}`, fd);
    } else {
      await axiosClient.post(`/car-make`, fd);
    }
    
    // use your dev-tools to inspect responses, not console.log()

    navigate(path);
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
    const response = err.response;
    if (response && response.status === 422) {
      setErrors(response.data.errors);
    }
  }
};


For Laravel to handle multipart/form-data PUT requests, you might need to resort to axios.post() and append _method=PUT
await axios.post(`/car-make/${encodeURIComponent(brand.id)}`, fd, {
  params: {
    _method: 'PUT',
  },
});

See PATCH and PUT Request Does not Working with form-data

I still think that this issue is caused by backend, I tried with postman and result is the same.  {"The name field is required."}

Is that for both of your PUT and POST requests? I don't know Laravel but perhaps it has the same dicey handling of PHP's multipart/form-data PUT data. You might need to use POST for both

POST request works for code frontend await axiosClient.post(/car-make, fd) and backend controller {$data = $request->validated();         if ($request->hasFile('logo')) {             $file = $request->file('logo');             $fileName = time() . '_' . $file->getClientOriginalName();             $filePath = $file->storeAs('logos', $fileName, 'public');             $data['logo']=$filePath;         } else {$data['logo'] = null;}          $carMake= CarMake::create([             'name' =>    $data['name'],             'logo' => $data['logo'],         ]);     } but PUT doesnt

Based on @Phil's help I finally found a solution which is that you have in frontend to go with method  POST and to define field named _method and value GET .. here is working code:
const onSubmit = async (e)=>{
e.preventDefault();
setErrors(null);

const fd = new FormData();
fd.append('_method','PUT');
Object.entries(brand).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if (value !== null) fd.append(key, value);
});


try {
  if (brand.id) {
    await axiosClient.post(`/car-make/${encodeURIComponent(brand.id)}`, fd)
    .then(({data})=>{
      //TODO show notification
      navigate(path);
  })
  .catch( (err) => {
      const response = err.response;
      if(response && response.status ===422){
        setErrors(response.data.errors);
      }
    });
  } else {
    await axiosClient.post(`/car-make`, fd)
    .then((data)=>{
      //TODO show notification
      navigate(path);
  })
  .catch( (err) => {
      const response = err.response;
      if(response && response.status ===422){
        setErrors(response.data.errors);
      }
    });
  }
  navigate(path);
} catch (err) {
  console.warn(err);
  const response = err.response;
  if (response && response.status === 422) {
    setErrors(response.data.errors);
  }
}

}
Thanks Phil!

Method validated() use for retrieving validated input.
Within your controller, instead of validated() method, use $request->validate()
So, your controller should be look likes
public function update(UpdateCarMakeRequest $request, CarMake $carMake)
    {
        Log::info('Update method called');
        Log::info('Update Brand Request - Raw Request Data:', $request->all());
        
        $data = $request->validate();
    
        if ($request->hasFile('logo')) {
            $file = $request->file('logo');
            $fileName = time() . '_' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $filePath = $file->storeAs('logo', $fileName, 'public');
            $data['logo'] = $filePath;
        } else {
            unset($data['logo']);
        }
    
        Log::info('Update Brand Request - Validated Data:', $data);
    
        $carMake->update($data);
    
        return new CarMakeResource($carMake);
    }

You can refer to docs for more information
